# Why is GROUP BY slower than a same-table join in this MySQL instance?

Tags: mysql

As a team, we're used to MS SQL Server. This is our first experience using MySQL and we were surprised by a particular behaviour.

We have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `People` (
  `PersonId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `AddressKey` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NameKey` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PersonId`),
  KEY `AddressKey` (`AddressKey`),
  KEY `NameKey` (`NameKey`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=243771506 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

It's very large - several hundred million records. And we've found it contains some duplicates.

To identify them, we first build a standard GROUP BY statement.

```
select NameKey, AddressKey, count(*) as dupes from People
group by NameKey, AddressKey having dupes > 1
limit 2;
```

Using EXPLAIN on this query yields:

```
id  select_type table           partitions  type    possible_keys       key     key_len ref                     rows        filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE      s1                          ALL     AddressKey,NameKey                                          215543661   100.00      Using where
1   SIMPLE      s2                          ref     AddressKey,NameKey  NameKey 768     s1.NameKey              5           0.92        Using index condition; Using where
```

However, this proved ridiculously slow. Doing a self-join is much faster:

```
select s1.* from People s1 join People s2 
on s1.NameKey = s2.NameKey and s1.AddressKey = s2.AddressKey
 where s1.SuppressionId <> s2.SuppressionId
limit 50;
```

Which gets the 50 records in about five minutes. Using EXPLAIN gives:

```
id  select_type table           partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows        filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE      People                      ALL                                     215543970   100.00      Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Based on the way SQL Server scans tables, we'd presumed the group by would be much faster, and it isn't. Why not? Is there anything we can do to improve the performance of this query?

Comment: Probably because it has to actually materialize the whole groups which could potentially have any number of rows in them. There's no way for it to short-circuit.

Comment: `group by NameKey, AddressKey`   needs the `index (NameKey, AddressKey)`  then the query would be faster.... You will get more information using `EXPLAIN [query]` you should also include this for both queries.

Comment: Are there indexes on the table?

Comment: Check the create table statement? @shawnt00

Comment: @RaymondNijland wait - both columns are indexed. Do I need to tell it to use both indexes?

Comment: No you need to create a single index with both columns... `create index idx_somename on People (AddressKey,NameKey)`

Comment: @JorgeCampos Ah! Well, that maybe what we've missed. I don't think that would have benefitted SQL Server in this instance. If someone wants to post that as an answer, I'll try it out.

Comment: It's a first suggestion from @RaymondNijland but even though you should test it first. It **may** not have big improvement.

Comment: Depens if the GROUP BY query needs to use a temporary table and quicksort or not "Using temporary; Using filesort" in extra column of the EXPLAIN output @JorgeCampos those are real MySQL preformance killers.  If MySQL can't hold the temporary table in memory it will create a MyISAM disk based temporary table.. So you are doing quicksort on disk with random disk i/o (because GROUP BY has a  automatic ORDER BY).. if you index correctly you will not run into this problem and MySQL will run like a speedtrain..

Comment: @RaymondNijland duly noted! Thanks for you input!

Comment: @RaymondNijland Your suspicion is correct. Using temporary; Using filesort was the "Extra" result from explain when using a group by.